# NullReferenceException thrown when attempting to get connectionstring from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net, web-config

I am trying to implement NLayering in my asp.net mvc 5 application and have separated the application into different layers, one being the data access layer(DAL). In my DAL when I try to access the connection string in my Insert method I get a NullReferenceException.  I have added the System.Configuration reference to my DAL project and a web.config file containing the ff code.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="JcSpaceConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=JcSpaceDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

JcSpaceDAL.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using JcSpaceEntities;

namespace JcSpaceDAL
{
    public class JcSpaceDAL
    {

        public static void Insert(JcSpaceAccount accountInfo)
        {
            string connectionString =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JcSpaceConnectionString"].ConnectionString;//This line causes the nullreferenceexception
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsert")) {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",   accountInfo.FirstName.ToString()+""+ accountInfo.LastName.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", accountInfo.Email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", acco    untInfo.DateOfBirth);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Why does it cause this?

Comment: You need to have same connection string section in your mvc project web.config as well

Comment: You should **debug/add logs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you added the JcSpaceConnectionString to the wrong web.config file. Did you add the web.config file to your DAL project? If so you'll need to move it to the MVC project instead.

Comment: Apparently I did. :) Its working now .  Currently I have my Insert method invoked in the action method.  If I change it to be invoked in the Business Logic Layer do I need to add the connections string in the BLL project?

Comment: Nope. The only place you'll need the connection string is in your web project. (The only other place you'll need to put your connection string is in another project that uses the entity framework, eg where your .edmx file is, but visual studio will do this automatically for you.. and this is only neccesary if you are using the entity framework wizards during development).